# Swift UIView custom view won't update after ViewController action

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, instance, viewcontroller

I want the stepper in the View Controller to update the color in my custom `UIView` every time it is clicked. I'm not sure if the problem is due to the instance of the class or that the values of the variables (`redd1`, `greenn1`, and `bluee1`) are not being changed.

This is my first file:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var colors = UIView1();
    @IBOutlet var redStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet var greenStepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet var blueStepper: UIStepper!

    @IBAction func redChange(sender: UIStepper)
    {
        redValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
        colors.redd1 = Double(sender.value);
        //self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    @IBAction func greenChange(sender: UIStepper)
    {
        greenValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
        colors.greenn1 = Double(sender.value);
        //self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    @IBAction func blueChange(sender: UIStepper)
    {
        blueValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
        colors.bluee1 = Double(sender.value);
        //self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
    } 
}
```

This is my second file:

```
class UIView1: UIView {
    var redd1 = 0.0;
    var greenn1 = 0.0;
    var bluee1 = 0.0;

    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)
    {
        let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -75.0, y: -40.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
        circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
        let startingColor = UIColor(red: (CGFloat(redd1))/255, green: (CGFloat(greenn1))/255, blue: (CGFloat(bluee1))/255, alpha: 1.0)
        circle.backgroundColor = startingColor;
        addSubview(circle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`drawRect` is only called when the view is being added, so in your example, `drawRect` is called once, and not after changing the stepper.

Instead, change your stepper file to:

```
@IBOutlet var redStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet var greenStepper: UIStepper!
@IBOutlet var blueStepper: UIStepper!

@IBAction func redChange(sender: UIStepper) {
    redValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
    colors.redd1 = Double(sender.value);
    updateColor()
}

@IBAction func greenChange(sender: UIStepper) {
    greenValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
    colors.greenn1 = Double(sender.value);
    updateColor()
}

@IBAction func blueChange(sender: UIStepper) {
    blueValue.text = Int(sender.value).description;
    colors.bluee1 = Double(sender.value);
    updateColor()
}
```

And then add the updateColor function to your UIView1 class:

```
class UIView1: UIView {

    var redd1 = 0.0;
    var greenn1 = 0.0;
    var bluee1 = 0.0;

    func updateColor() {
        let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: -75.0, y: -40.0, width: 200.0, height: 200.0))
        circle.layer.cornerRadius = 50.0;
        let startingColor = UIColor(red: (CGFloat(redd1))/255, green: (CGFloat(greenn1))/255, blue: (CGFloat(bluee1))/255, alpha: 1.0)
        circle.backgroundColor = startingColor;
        addSubview(circle);
    }
}
```

Comment: First, try adding print(sender.value) in your IBActions to make sure you're receiving the correct value. If that's happening, add print(redd1), print(greenn1), and print(bluee1) to your updateColor() function to see if's receiving values, or running at all.

Comment: is it because the updateColor function doesn't override the drawRect function

Comment: You can eliminate the drawRect function, you don't need it. If updateColor is being run that means the circle is being added. I noticed you have negative values for the x and y though, try setting those both to 0 to make sure your circle isn't being placed somewhere that isn't viewable.